# How to capture varargs

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, powermock

I have static method, and i want to capture **varargs**

```
Executor ex = new Executor();
ex.execute(String nodeName, boolean status, Property ... properties);

ArgumentCaptor<Property> propertyCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Property.class);
verify(ex).execute(anyString(), anyBoolean(), propertyCaptor.capture);
```

**propertyCaptor**.getValue() - doesn't work????

Comment: The class for `Property...` is `Property[].class`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to test, but the following works:

```
class SpecialExecutor implements Executor {
        @Override
        public void execute(Runnable command) {

        }

        public void execute(String nodeName, boolean status, Property... properties) {

        }
    };

    @Test
    public void test() {
        SpecialExecutor ex = new SpecialExecutor();

        ArgumentCaptor<Property> propertyCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Property.class);
        verify(ex).execute(anyString(), anyBoolean(), any(Property[].class));
    }
```

Comment: did you run this code? This work if you have case: one varargs parameter, but this don't work if you have > 1 parameters.